# Why does getInt inside RDD[Row].map give "error: value getInt is not a member of Any"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I'm new in Scala-Spark but I need to develop my final project bachelor with this.

I'm trying from a data to build a K-means algorithm.
The data are from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/murderaccountability/homicide-reports

I read the file with the data.
Create a case class like:

```
case class CrimeReport (Record_ID: String, Agency_Name: String, 
City: String, State: String, Year: Int, Month: Int, Crime_Type: String, 
Crime_Solved: String, Victim_Sex: String, Victim_Age: Int, Victim_Race: String, 
Perpetrator_Sex: String, Perpetrator_Age: String, Perpetrator_Race: String, Relationship: String, Victim_Count: String)
```

I map my data with the case class. As, for example, the month are String and I need Int (to create after my features vector) I define a function to parse this:

```
    //Parsear Month:    String  ===>    Int
    def parseMonthToNumber(month: String) : Int = {
        var result = 0
        month match {
            case "January" => result = 1
            case "February" => result = 2
            case "March" => result = 3
            case "April" => result = 4
            case "May" => result = 5
            case "June" => result = 6
            case "July" => result = 7
            case "August" => result = 8
            case "September" => result = 9
            case "October" => result = 10
            case "November" => result = 11
            case _ => result = 12
        }
        result
    }

    data = sc.textFile (... .csv)
    val data_split = data.map(line => line.split(","))

    val allData = data_split.map(p => CrimeReport(p(0).toString,
    p(1).toString, p(2).toString, p(3).toString, parseInt(p(4)),
     parseMonthToNumber(p(5)), p(6).toString, p(7).toString, p(8).toString,
     parseInt(p(9)), p(10).toString, p(11).toString, p(12).toString,
     p(13).toString, p(14).toString, p(15).toString))
//DataFrame
val allDF = allData.toDF()

//convert data to RDD which will be passed to KMeans
val rowsRDD = allDF.rdd.map( x => 

                (x(0).getString, x.getString(1), x.getString(2), x.getString(3), x(4).getInt, x(5).getInt, x.getString(6), x.getString(7), x.getString(8), x(9).getInt, x.getString(10), x.getString(11), x.getString(12), x.getString(13), x.getString(14), x.getString(15))
                )
```

But I get this error:

```
error: value getInt is not a member of Any
                       (x(0).getString, x.getString(1), x.getString(2), x.getString(3), x(4).getInt, x(5).getInt, x.getString(6), x.getString(7), x.getString(8), x(9).getInt, x.getString(10), x.getString(11), x.getString(12), x.getString(13), x.getString(14), x.getString(15))
                                                                                                          ^
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the latest version of [Spark 2.1.1](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-1-1-released.html).

Let me first ask you the question about why you convert a DataFrame to a `RDD[Row]` to execute KMeans since there is [DataFrame-based KMeans implementation in Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans).

Read up on [KMeans in Spark MLlib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#k-means).

I would not do this since [Spark MLlib's RDD-based API is deprecated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html#mllib-rdd-based-api):

> This page documents sections of the MLlib guide for the RDD-based API (the `spark.mllib` package). Please see the MLlib Main Guide for the DataFrame-based API (the `spark.ml` package), which is now the primary API for MLlib.

---

With that said, let's see what issue you face.

If I were you (and disregarded the advice to stick to Spark MLlib's DataFrame-based API), I'd do the following:

```
// val allDF = allData.toDF()
val allDF = allData.toDS
```

With the above you'd have a `Dataset[CrimeReport]` that is much more pleasant to work with than a pure `Row`.

After you've done the conversion, you could do

```
val rowsRDD = allDF.rdd.map { x => ... }
```

where `x` is of your type `CrimeReport` and am sure you'll know what to do with it.

---

To answer your question directly, the reason for the error:

> error: value getInt is not a member of Any

is that `x(5)` (and others) are of type `Any` so you have to cast it to your type or just replace `x(5)` with `x.getInt(5)`.

See the scaladoc of [Row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row).

Comment: Thank so much! :) with your help I was able to realize where was the error. There was two: first of all, replace DataFrame with DataSet; The other one was in val rowsRDD = allDF.rdd.map { x => ... } I had to call the attributes with the name of the column, i.e do the call with the names i had been define in my case class, no with the position (e.g x(5),x(6),...)

Answer (score 0):

How do we then use kmeans when we are dealing with String datatypes in a case class instead of doubles? This code I have will not work as vector expects a double.

```
// Passing in Crime_Type, Crime_Solved, Perpetrator_Race to KMeans as 
the attributes we want to use to assign the instance to a cluster.

val vectors = allDF.rdd.map(r => Vectors.dense( r.Crime_Type, r.Crime_Solved, r.Perpetrator_Race ))

//KMeans model with 2 clusters and 10 iterations

val kMeansModel = KMeans.train(vectors, 2, 10)
```

Comment: I answer you in a new comment just to you were able to see the format clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You should define as *int/double* the attributes which you want use in the method Vector.dense.

After, when you will be mapping your case class with the data in the file, you should call the function which you defined before. As you can see here:

```
val data_split = data.map(line => line.split(","))

val allData = data_split.map(p => 
                                CrimeReport(p(0).toString, p(1).toString, p(2).toString, p(3).toString, parseInt(p(4)), parseMonthToNumber(p(5)), p(6).toString, parseSolved(p(7)), parseSex(p(8)), parseInt(p(9)), parseRaceToNumber(p(10)), p(11).toString, p(12).toString, p(13).toString, p(14).toString, p(15).toString))
```

An the functions are:

```
//Filter and Cleaning data      =>    Crime Solved
def parseSolved (solved: String): Int = {
    var result = 0
    solved match {
        case "Yes" => result = 1
        case _ => result = 0
     }
     result
}
```

Or:

```
//Parsear   Victim_Race:    String  ===>    Int
def parseRaceToNumber (crType : String) : Int = {
    var result = 0
    val race = crType.split("/")
    race(0) match {
        case "White" => result = 1
        case "Black" => result = 2
        case "Asian" => result = 3
        case "Native American" => result = 4
        case _ => result = 0
    }
    result
}
```